# Update on a table is taking long time

Tags: sql-server

This is my First Question on Blog.

I am facing issues with the Update Statement.

I am using one server (Source Server - SS) and want to update a table that is on another server (Target Server - TS) on daily basis. But the update is taking long time to process.

```
SS.Table1 - Row count over 5 Million
TS.Table2 - Row count over 50 Million
```

Every day i want to update TS.Table2 with some 500 records from SS.Table1.

Since both he tables are big, i have extracted the records from SS.Table1 into Temp Table #Temp

```
Update TS.Table2
set TargetTable.ColumnName = SourceTable.ColumnName
from TS.Table2 T
JOIN #Temp S
on T.Col1 = S.Col1
and T.Col2 = S.Col2
```

Note 1: Both Col1 and Col2 are having clustered indexes on Target Table and also on Source Table

Note 2: When selecting the data it is doing in Milli Seconds with same join condition.

Note 3: I Did try updatind the Target table using CTE but there is no performance improvement.

Note 4: Even for updating one record this is taking the same time as 500 records

Note 5: I have in some online articles, that dropping the indexes on Target Table and Recreating may improve performance and done the same but there is no improvement.

If not provided enough information, please respond.

Regards

Comment: Just noticed that you've stated this is using linked servers, so that is going to be the likely cause. I'm afraid I don't have an answer (I don't really delve into Linked Server's often), thus the comemnt to explain. Most likely the Server you are running the query on is having the retreive the **entire** table from the linked server. Then, afterwards, the `JOIN` criteria happens, and after that, the host can process the `UPDATE` commands. This is why is takes so long, as the index you have isn't really being used on the remote host and it takes ages to transfer the data.

Comment: Hello,I thought this might be the cause but this is working absolutely fine for other objects. This is the only issue iam having with this object.

Comment: Are those other objects as large (both height and width)? What queries are you running against those objects? Simply saying "I'm not having a problem with other objects" isn't really that insightful.

Comment: The objects are nearly same size mate and updates are upto 1000... we are pulling data from different objects whch are nearly the same size and same opeartion as object in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in the past. I was using SQL Server 2008. That version requires sysadmin rights to access the remote statistics. Without the remote statistics, the risk is that SQL Server will retrieve the remote data (50M rows) and execute locally. 
http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/linked-servers-and-distributed-queries/
I bypassed the problem using openquery that enforces the remote execution.

In your case, you could write 500 rows in a remote staging table and use openquery to execute the update entirely in the remote server.

Comment: I would second this suggestion.  Given the Linked Server(s), a different query or indexes will probably not help, but a different approach could work miracles.  Consider adding another column, if possible, that indicates the last update date/time on the Source Server table, and push that subset of rows over first, then apply the UPDATE to the Target Server.

Comment: Hello,Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Unfortunately this is happening only for this object. I have similar process on same servers and same databases but they are working fine for me.

Comment: I have checked the fragmentation levels and statistics update. We are rebuilding or reorganising indexes and updating statistics every night before the actual job is running..#

Comment: The remote statistics are useless if the local server cannot access them. Have you checked that? You should copy the changes in a remote table and execute the update locally, manually. If it works fine, it means it's the right direction, otherwise you have to tune your query of the indexes.

Comment: Even if you assume that SQL server is misbehaving, you can use openquery to enforce the separation of remote and local data. the idea is change the query in order to minimized the amount of data that travels along the two servers